# Adding ArcGIS Server feature service to ArcMap data frame using Python?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, feature-service

There's an external ArcGIS Server that I've been manually going into through ArcCatalog to pull down feature services and save them off as feature classes. I do this twice a month, so I would like to explore if it's possible to do this automatically with Python/ArcPy.

Is this possible?

Current process is that I save off 4 feature classes from 3 feature services. My process is to make a connection to the server in Catalog --> drag the FS from Catalog into my TOC --> right click on the layer of interest and save off as a feature class to my local GDB.

Comment: How many features are you saving and what is your manual workflow for saving them?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. There are even examples in the documentation. Please [Edit] the question to provide clarifications.

Answer (score 3):

[Quick Tips: Consuming Feature Services with Geoprocessing](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-desktop/analytics/quick-tips-consuming-feature-services-with-geoprocessing/) explains the various techniques to do this.

The absolute easiest and shortest solution would be to:

1. Drag the feature service into ArcMap
2. Right click and Save as Layer file (LYR)
3. Run Copy Features on that LYR file:

---

```
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('C:/temp/FeatureService.lyr', 'c:/temp/LocalCopy.shp")
```

Otherwise, give a read of the blog and see how you can use **arcpy.FeatureSet** to make a query and "Save" data.

Answer (score 1):

You have two different questions here:

1) To save features from an ArcGIS Feature service you can query the service and then use the [JSON To Features tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/json-to-features.htm).

The most straightforward way to query a service in Python is using `requests`, which already comes with the ArcGIS Python installation. After querying the service you save a JSON file to your mahcine and then use the JSON To Features tool to convert that JSON file to features and save them inside a GDB. Here is a snippet that does this process by getting all the features from the service (it is up to you to do the query so you get the 4 feature classes you mentioned, if they don't represent all the features in the service).

```
import json

import arcpy
import requests

# arcpy env settings
arcpy.env.workspace = 'path_to_your_gdb'

# get data from rest service
params = {'where': '1=1', 'outFields': '*', 'f': 'pjson', 'returnGeometry': True}
r = requests.get('service_url/query', params)
data = r.json()

# save JSON as a Feature class
json_path = 'path_to_rest_service.json'
with open(json_path, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
arcpy.JSONToFeatures_conversion(json_path, 'output_fc')
```

For information about all the parameters you can pass to the query be sure to read the [ArcGIS REST API documentation for the query operation](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/query-feature-service-.htm).

You would have to do this for each of the three services you are getting features from.

2) To automatically add the new feature to a DataFrame you have to use the `arcpy.mapping` module. First you need to specify the MXD and the DataFrame you are going to add the features. Second you have to create an `arcpy.mapping.Layer()` object for each Feature Class in the GDB. Finally you have to add the layer to the DataFrame using the `arcpy.mapping.AddLayer()` function. Here is a snippet showing this process for one Feature Class:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = 'path_to_your_gdb'

# specify MXD and Data Frame
mxd_fn = r'path_to_mxd'
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd_fn)
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

# create layer from Feature Class and add it to the Data Frame
lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer('my_feature_class')
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, lyr, 'TOP')

# refresh view, TOC and save MXD
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
mxd.save()
```

In case you wanted to remove previous layers from the Data Frame, use the `arcpy.RemoveLayer()` function.